# jQuery: Get (1) selected Value when working with multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I am trying to get the selected Value from each Select-Dropdown (1 Option), when clicking on it seperately. Currently when I change the selected Value from my first dropdown it shows the correct Value. But when I click on another dropdown and change the Value it keeps displaying the Value from the first dropdown. The dropdowns are created dynamically in a table (foreach loop) from a MYSQL database. Therefore they have the same Id (#dropdownId), which might be a problem. The alert fires for both dropdowns but the "selected" Value is only correct when effectively changing the first dropdown. When selecting something from another dropdown it will always show the last selected Value of the first dropdown. (same for id)

```
$(document).on('change',$('#dropdownId'),function(){
        let itemVal = $('#dropdownId').find(':selected').val();
        var itemId = $('#dropdownId').find(':selected').attr('id');
        alert(itemVal);
        $.ajax({
            //..
            success: function(html){
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please include your html, and `('change',$('#dropdownId'),function(){` should be `('change','#dropdownId',function(){`

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore they have the same Id (#dropdownId), which might be a
>   problem - YES This is a problem.

Id's should always be unique. You should switch to using a common `className` for your event delegation:

Use a common class like `myDropDown` and apply that to each one of your drop downs generated by your MYSQL:

HTML:

```
<select class="myDropDown"></select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','.myDropDown',function(){
        //$(this) refers to the drop down which triggered the event
        let itemVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        var itemId = $(this).find(':selected').attr('id');
        alert(itemVal);
        //AJAX Part
```

Comment: @Robin Something tells me it isn't actually solved if they all have the same id value, but ok.

Comment: you're right.. it's not working properly.. I have to look at it again, just went over it too quickly.. thank you! this must be the problem!

Comment: so the main issue actually was the typo in my jQuery function, but I also changed my dropdowns accordingly to handle the events with an own class as you have described, so the ids are unique. Thanks again and all the best.